# How to centre a nav bar in CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

I want to have a navigation bar at the top of my webpage to be centred. I have been searching for hours and just cannot get this to work.

here is my HTML that I want to have centred.

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>        
    <li><a href="#">My CV profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

and here is some CSS I found online that doesnt quite work entirely.

```
#nav {
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
padding: 0;  }

#nav ul {
list-style: none;
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0; }

#nav li {
float: left; }

#nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 8px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'calibri light', arial;
color: #069; }
```

I am a fairly clueless developer as it is but am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Here it works.just changing margin-left attribute according to your requirment

```css
#nav {
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin-left:300px;
padding: 0;  }

#nav ul {
list-style: none;
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0; }

#nav li {
float: left; }

#nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 8px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'calibri light', arial;
color: #069; }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>        
    <li><a href="#">My CV profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, made my day.

Answer (score 0):

You can set text-align center to the parent and display: inline-block in the children to center. Example:

```css
#nav {
background: #fff;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;  
}

#nav ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0; }

#nav li {
display: inline-block;
}

#nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 8px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'calibri light', arial;
color: #069; }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>        
    <li><a href="#">My CV profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Very useful, works perfectly